# tridion event system for linked schema

Tags: 2013-sp1, event-system, sdl-tridion

I would like to write an event system to trigger on component save and update the external URL (embedded link) to https://www.xxxx.com. Please suggest the best approach to find the URL field of embedded link schema (multiple valued) of a component.

Comment: What have you considered? Read about? Tried?